# How to downgrade from CUDA 11.4 to 10.2 & add sm_35 - CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I'm trying to run a piece of code on Pytorch, but I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
```

I've narrowed down the issue to be a missmatch of CUDA versions. My machine has 2 GPUs:
a GeForce GTX 650 (compute capability 3.0) and a Tesla K40c (compute capability 3.5). I've checked the compute capabilities here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus.
My `nvidia-smi` command gives the following:

[nvidia-smi output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkvvs.png) (Driver Version: 470.57.02 & CUDA Version: 11.4)

While my `nvcc -V` command gives the following:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

The 10.1 version exists because I tried to install that CUDA version, specifically, following the instructions elsewhere (for example: https://medium.com/@anarmammadli/how-to-install-cuda-10-2-cudnn-7-6-5-and-samples-on-ubuntu-18-04-2493124478ca)

Also, I've installed `cudatoolkit` with `conda`, and so on my `conda list` I have the following entry:

```
...
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h6bb024c_0
...
```

In accordance with https://github.com/moi90/pytorch_compute_capabilities/blob/main/table.md I've also installed the 1.8.0 PyTorch version.

However, in Python 3.7.11:

```
Python 3.7.11 (default, Jul 27 2021, 14:32:16)
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.8.1'
>>> torch.version.cuda
'10.1'
>>> torch.cuda.get_arch_list()
['sm_37', 'sm_50', 'sm_60', 'sm_61', 'sm_70', 'sm_75', 'compute_37']
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
```

I don't have `sm_35` available, which I need to use the Tesla K40. I believe this is the reason why I keep getting the `CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device` error. I've also tried all the above for version 10.2 of CUDA, same result.

Comment: You'll need to find and install [a version of PyTorch that is built with support for cc3.5](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/k40-is-not-supported-by-pytorch/80356).  The driver you already have installed is fine.

Comment: So it seems I require Pytorch with version before 1.5 ?

Comment: What binary support a given Pytorch version has isn’t a function of the CUDA toolkit or Pytorch (within support limits), it is what binary support the Pytorch developers choose to distribute. The prefer to sacrifice older hardware support for smaller binary package size. You can probably build a more modern version of Pytorch with a CUDA 10.x toolkit yourself. If not you will have to take what they give, and that will be very old

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my problem. As stated in the comments, I required a version of PyTorch that supports `sm_35` compute capability. It had little to do with the current CUDA version. In the end, I found these binaries:

https://blog.nelsonliu.me/2020/10/13/newer-pytorch-binaries-for-older-gpus/

I finally fixed the issue by creating a new environment and running:

```
pip install torch==1.3.1+cu92 -f https://nelsonliu.me/files/pytorch/whl/torch_stable.html
```